# Tracking transactions in both directions

Tags: tracking

I have an example of a transaction. I deleted some fields which don't play any role for my question. Also I reduced large hashes and IDs.

```
{
 "txid": "8d554",
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "d3117",
      "vout": 0
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "value": 1.99995000,"address":"mrL8SS",
      "n": 0
    }, 
    {
      "value": 3.00000000, "address":"mtK8r",
      "n": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

From this transaction I can find out which transaction was used for paying outputs of this transaction. Because those transaction is in `vin` field. Its txID is `d3117`. So if I want i will be able to find this transaction by using bitcoin client RPC API: `bitcoin-cli gettransaction d3117`. 
  But what if i want to find out, which transaction used THIS transaction as input? Could you guys please tell me, if it's possible or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible without looking through all the transactions after this one and finding the one which spent it. Most block explorers keep a database of the transactions so you could look it up on one of them.

Comment: I really was hoping that there was some way to do that. Well, thank you very much for answering anyway!